$lookup accross 2 collections for ID exists takes too much time on Mongo
I am using a Quartz + Spring batch Cluster to read documents from Mongo for bulk processing. Since i cannot tag(add a read flag) the original document as read , i add the ID of the read document into a migration collection and compare the ID's across the collection using a $lookup with below code in aggregate pipeline
$lookup:{
from:'migration_coll',
localField: '_id',
foreignField: '_id,
pipeline:[
{
   $project: {
      "_id":1
   }
 }
],
as:'migrtedDocuments'
]}

I typed in the above part to get an idea on how i am using the pipeline to do a look up using _id's across the collection and then projecting on id only as well to increase the speed. However with large collection size, the Query is really slow. With 2 million plus records it is taking more than 10 to 15s to return a count.
Questions:

is there any better way to do this ?.
What else can i use to keep a tab if i cant modify the existing document?

I am kind of stuck on this issue. Any help is appreciated

Lookups are slow on large collections. In worst case it's O(mn) complexity, but in most cases there is room for optimisation using indices. You will need to get exact query from the slowlog  and profile it - by default mongo logs all queries longer than 100 millis. The query in the question is a mix of 2 syntaxes of $lookup and there is nothing to answer to that. As a side note, it would make sense to ask how to resolve the original problem. People may suggest a better option than using lookups.
